# How to completely remove emails in OS X?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, data-synchronization, gmail

I added my Google account to my MacBookPro and then I decided to fetch my Google mails by using the "Mail" application..

Then I decided to keep the Google account but remove the "Mail" application from the Google account settings and kept only Calendar and Contacts.

Now when I search for anything in spotlight, it still finds things from my previously fetched Google mails.

How can I clean all the fetched mails completely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't have other Mail accounts with data that you want, quit Mail.app and **delete the entire contents of ~/Library/Mail/**

If you *do* have other accounts and only want to remove your Gmail account, quit Mail.app, open the V2 folder inside the above path and delete the folder relevant to the particular account that you want removed.